# How to group variables with the same value

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I want to write an efficient code, can I get help?

for example

When there are four dictionary variables below,

```python
v1 = {'title':'title1', 'number1':1, 'number2':2, 'number3':3, 'number4':4, 'number5':5}
v2 = {'title':'title2', 'number1':1, 'number2':2, 'number3':3, 'number4':4, 'number5':55}
v3 = {'title':'title3', 'number1':1, 'number2':2, 'number3':33, 'number4':4, 'number5':55}

v4 = {'title':'title4', 'number1':1, 'number2':4567, 'number3':8910, 'number4':5177, 'number5':1511}
```

If the same number of values is 3 or more by comparing the values of the key 'number1', 'number2', 'number3', 'number4', and 'number5', we want to group them.

Expected result:

```python
[['title1', 'title2', 'title3'], ['title4']]
```

It doesn't have to be a result like an expected result, anyway, it just needs to be grouped.

Can I help you? Thank you

Comment: How would you get `title3` out of the four dictionaries you gave?  Can you give the *actual* expected result you want to achieve given those four dictionaries?

Comment: Title3 doesn't exist in your example. I'd fix that for you but you know better than me what you're trying to ask

Comment: For three or more dicts to be grouped together, do they *all* have to share 3 values in common, or does each just need to share 3 values in common with one other dict in the group?

Comment: Also the second instance of title2 should "group with" title1 so what ever that means.

Comment: sorry, edit my question

Comment: What happened to `title4`?  Shouldn't it be in a group by itself?

Comment: Yes right edit my question

Comment: Titles 1, 2 and 4 all have the same value of `number1`. Why are they not in the same group?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Because *one* matching number isn't 3 or more, and the other four don't match.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Pychopath and OP

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach where groups are iteratively combined until there are no remaining ways to combine them:

```
vars = [
    {'title':'title1', 'number1':1, 'number2':2, 'number3':3, 'number4':4, 'number5':5},
    {'title':'title2', 'number1':1, 'number2':2, 'number3':3, 'number4':44, 'number5':55},
    {'title':'title3', 'number1':11, 'number2':22, 'number3':3, 'number4':4, 'number5':5},
    {'title':'title4', 'number1':1, 'number2':4567, 'number3':8910, 'number4':5177, 'number5':1511},
]
groups = [[var] for var in vars]

while True:
    for group in groups:
        for other in groups:
            if group == other:
                continue
            if any(sum(
                v == var2[k] 
                for k, v in var1.items() 
                if k.startswith("number")
            ) >= 3 for var1 in group for var2 in other):
                group.extend(other)
                groups.remove(other)
                break
        else:
            continue
        break
    else:
        break

print([[var['title'] for var in group] for group in groups])
```

prints:

```
[['title1', 'title2', 'title3'], ['title4']]
```

Comment: I'm trying to think of some corner case that breaks this but it looks good. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

For n variables you can make an nxn array that represents the connectedness for any pairwise combination. So that connected(n1,n2) is 1 if var n1 and n2 share more than 3 variables else 0. Then take a vector of n elements populated by zeros and a 1 in it for a given variable and multiply it by your connectedness matrix n times to get a vector where non-zero values represent membership in this grouping. After you've done this for one variable repeat for remaining variables that have not yet been included in a grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to frame this problem using graphs.

Define a graph with nodes corresponding to titles and an edge drawn between to titles if the agree of at least 3 out of 5 number attributes. You can find connected components using networkx as follows:

```
vs = [v1, v2, v3, v4]

import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

num_cols = [f"number{i}" for i in range(1, 6)]

g = nx.Graph()

g.add_nodes_from([v["title"] for v in vs])
for v1, v2 in combinations(vs, 2):
  if sum(v1[k] == v2[k] for k in num_cols) >= 3:
    g.add_edge(v1["title"], v2["title"])

groups = [list(c) for c in nx.connected_components(g)]
# [['title1', 'title3', 'title2'], ['title4']]
```

Alternatively, you may want to find groups such that *any* two elements in the group agree on at least three number attributes. In this case, you will be looking for cliques in the graph:

```
cliques = [list(c) for c in nx.find_cliques(g)]
# [['title1', 'title3', 'title2'], ['title4']]
```

The two approaches result in the same output for this example, but not in general. In the second (clique) approach, an element may appear in multiple groups.